# Node.js and Exrpess: Proper handling of variables passed at res.render()

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

One of my routes to my app, renders an HTML (ejs actually) file, passing a variable as well.

```
myFunc(username).then(user=>{
        res.render('normalHTML.ejs')
    }).catch(err => {
        res.render('error.ejs', {overwrite: err.code === 'NONEXISTANT_USER'});

});
```

The client javascript code on '`error.ejs`' checks for the overwrite variable and changes the view.

The problem is, the same '`error.ejs`' file is being rendered from outer routes as well. But on those routes, i don't pass the '`overwrite`' variable.

But the js on the '`error.ejs`' is the same and an error is triggered.
Specifically:

"`overwrite is not defined`" error.

This is the client code on '`error.ejs`':

```
<script>
  var checking_for_user = <%- JSON.stringify(overwrite) %> ;
  if (checking_for_user) {
    document.querySelector('.msg .text-center').innerHTML='Error! Please go back to the <a href="/index">Index Page</a>';
  }
</script>
```

What ways are there to mitigate this?
Perhaps passing a null variable to the other routes?
Perhaps better handling at client side, on '`error.ejs`'?

Answer (score 0):

How about checking if `overwrite` is defined? Something in the lines of

```
<script>
  var checking_for_user = <%- typeof(overwrite) != "undefined" && JSON.stringify(overwrite) %> ;
  if (checking_for_user) {
    document.querySelector('.msg .text-center').innerHTML='Error! Please go back to the <a href="/index">Index Page</a>';
  }
</script>
```